# How do I exclude proxy env vars from pods for Kubernetes/OpenShift?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

There are a set of proxy environment variables (http_proxy, HTTP_PROXY, https_proxy, HTTPS_PROXY, no_proxy, NO_PROXY) in my OpenShift pods that I did not explicitly include and I do not want them there.

For example

```
$ oc run netshoot -it --image docker-registry.default.svc:5000/default/netshoot -- bash
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.

bash-4.4$ env | grep -i proxy | sort
HTTPS_PROXY=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8081/
HTTP_PROXY=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8081/
NO_PROXY=.cluster.local,.mydomain.nz,.localdomain.com,.svc,10.xx.xx.xx,127.0.0.1,172.30.0.1,app01.mydomain.nz,app02.mydomain.nz,inf01.mydomain.nz,inf02.mydomain.nz,mst01.mydomain.nz,localaddress,localhost,.edpay.nz
http_proxy=xx.xx.xx.xx:8081
https_proxy=xx.xx.xx.xx:8081
no_proxy=.cluster.local,.mydomain.nz,.localdomain.com,.svc,10.xx.xx.xx,127.0.0.1,172.30.0.1,app01.mydomain.nz,app02.mydomain.nz,inf01.mydomain.nz,inf02.mydomain.nz,mst01.mydomain.nz,localaddress,localhost,.edpay.nz
```

I have yet to track down how those env vars are getting into my pods.

I am not [Setting Proxy Environment Variables in Pods](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/http_proxies.html#setting-environment-variables-in-pods).

```
$ oc get pod netshoot-1-hjp2p -o yaml | grep -A 10 env
[no output]

$ oc get deploymentconfig netshoot -o yaml | grep -A 10 env
[no output]
```

I am not [Creating Pod Presets](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/pod_preset.html#dev-guide-pod-presets-create)

```
$ oc get podpresets --all-namespaces
No resources found.
```

Docker on my master/app nodes have no proxy env vars.

```
$ grep -i proxy /etc/sysconfig/docker
[no output]
```

Kubelet (openshift-node) on my master/app nodes have no proxy env vars.

```
$ grep -i proxy /etc/sysconfig/atomic-openshift-node
[no output]
```

Master components on my master nodes have no proxy env vars.

```
$ grep -i proxy /etc/sysconfig/atomic-openshift-master
[no output]

$ grep -i proxy /etc/sysconfig/atomic-openshift-master-api
[no output]

$ grep -i proxy /etc/sysconfig/atomic-openshift-master-controllers
[no output]
```

Contents of sysconfig files (not including comments)

```
$ cat /etc/sysconfig/atomic-openshift-master
OPTIONS="--loglevel=0"
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml

$ cat /etc/sysconfig/atomic-openshift-node
OPTIONS=--loglevel=2
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/origin/node/node-config.yaml
IMAGE_VERSION=v3.9.51

$ cat /etc/sysconfig/docker
OPTIONS=' --selinux-enabled       --signature-verification=False         --insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16'
if [ -z "${DOCKER_CERT_PATH}" ]; then
    DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/etc/docker
fi
ADD_REGISTRY='--add-registry registry.access.redhat.com'

$ cat /etc/sysconfig/atomic-openshift-master-api
OPTIONS=--loglevel=2 --listen=https://0.0.0.0:8443 --master=https://mst01.mydomain.nz:8443
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml
OPENSHIFT_DEFAULT_REGISTRY=docker-registry.default.svc:5000

$ cat /etc/sysconfig/atomic-openshift-master-controllers
OPTIONS=--loglevel=2 --listen=https://0.0.0.0:8444
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml
OPENSHIFT_DEFAULT_REGISTRY=docker-registry.default.svc:5000
```

I'm at a loss as to how those proxy env vars are getting into my pods.

Versions:

- OpenShift v3.9.51

Comment: Are you using a Dockerfile? Can you check/post the content if you do?

Comment: What are the contents of  `/etc/sysconfig/openshift-master` and `/etc/sysconfig/openshift-node` at the host level ?

Comment: Are they defined as part of the image rather than the runtime environment? How was the image built, in OpenShift?

Comment: Using a Dockerfile but the proxy env vars are _not_ defined in it or in the base image. It's based on this one https://hub.docker.com/r/nicolaka/netshoot/

Comment: The image is built in OpenShift using a BuildConfig (that doesn't have the proxy env vars) and invoked with `oc start-build -n default netshoot`.

Comment: Added contents of sysconfig files to question

Comment: Have any of these been set https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install/configuring_inventory_file.html#advanced-install-configuring-global-proxy

Comment: Ah sorry. I should have mentioned it's a 3.9 install.

Comment: We had `openshift_http_proxy`, `openshift_https_proxy`, and `openshift_no_proxy` set at one point but now we're trying to remove them.

Comment: The 3.9 docs for the same https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/build_defaults_overrides.html#ansible-setting-global-build-defaults

Answer (score 1):

We finally figured this out. We had `openshift_http_proxy`, `openshift_https_proxy`, and `openshift_no_proxy` set in our installer inventory variables as per [Configuring Global Proxy Options](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#advanced-install-configuring-global-proxy).

We knew that this meant it also implicitly set the `openshift_builddefaults_http_proxy`, `openshift_builddefaults_https_proxy`, and `openshift_builddefaults_no_proxy` installer inventory variables and according to the docs

> This variable defines the HTTP_PROXY environment variable inserted into builds using the BuildDefaults admission controller. If you do not define this parameter but define the openshift_http_proxy parameter, the openshift_http_proxy value is used. Set the openshift_builddefaults_http_proxy value to False to disable default http proxy for builds regardless of the openshift_http_proxy value.

What we did *not* know (and I would argue is not at all clear from the description above), is that setting those installer inventory variables sets the `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, and `NO_PROXY` env vars permanently within your images.

It's painfully apparent now when we look back on the build logs and see lines like this

```
...
Step 2/19 : ENV "HTTP_PROXY" "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" "HTTPS_PROXY" "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" "NO_PROXY" "127.0.0.1,localhost,172.30.0.1,.svc,.cluster.local" "http_proxy" "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" "https_proxy" "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" "no_proxy" "127.0.0.1,localhost,172.30.0.1,.svc,.cluster.local"
...
```

We couldn't exclude proxy env vars from the pods because those env vars were set at build time.